# How to set style for an element in typescript?(Angular)

Tags: css, angular, typescript

How can I set the background colour for an item within an if statement in typescript? I used `querySelector` but the answer can use anything to achieve the result.

The selector is `(.mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected)`.

Here is the code in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pujfgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, I want to help but there are some errors in stackblitz. Could you improve it?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! The error is because I put the style in querySelector. I will comment that line.

Comment: I edited! Can you please see it?

Comment: The selector is .mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected

Answer (score 4):

The stackblitz example can be helpful but there is a lot in there to summarise what you are askign for, this answer is a generic way of doing so, meaning you can apply it to your code as and where you see fit.

Declare you boolean.

```
public value = true;
```

Now declare the CSS class you would like to use.

```
.exmaple-class {
    background: red;
}
```

Then on the selected HTML element you want to apply the class.

```
<div [class.example-class]="value === true"></div>
```

or just

```
<div [class.example-class]="value"></div>
```

As this still equates to true. If `value` were set to `false` then the class would not be applied.

If you want to start building more classes and options for a specific element you can look into [Angular's ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle).

Add in this, think this is what you are also asking for, little different. It only runs after the view is loaded, not working in you example because the HTML has not yet been drawn.

```
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void
  {
      this.changeColour();
  }

  public changeColour() {
      document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(".mat-step-icon-selected").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

Then add a click event to ensure that each time you select something the selector is updated.

```
<div class="center-contrainer" (click)=changeColour()>
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing. How can I use this selector(.mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected)  instead of one class?

Comment: Can you please show me how to use it with the above selector?

Comment: made an edit if you want to take a look should be able to get what you want from there :-)

Comment: i would like to have these selectors together not separate to have the second icon background

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, the above will turn the background to red for each of the selectors

Comment: there is only one selector not 3

Comment: something like this  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(".mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected").style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  }

Comment: So, the three selectors are in the array, and for each item in the array, it is setting the colour. querySelector only works how you intend with one item at a time. The above will apply it to all 3

Comment: there are 3 classes that refers to one element not 3 elements

Comment: they are written without comma in css

Comment: so i want to change the background color only for the icon 2 that has selector (.mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected). Now it changed for these 3 individual classes so it has 3 background colors(for mat-step, mat-step-header and mat-step-icon-selected)

Comment: so just do document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(.mat-step:nth-child(2)).style.backgroundColor = 'red'; in the afterviewInit

Comment: but for this it has background for all step 2. i would like for the icon 2 selected thats why i put other 2 classes.

Comment: i put all three classes because i would like to have the icon in the step 2. You put the last class there. the css is .mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected{
  background-color: red;
}

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_queryselectorall_multiple

Comment: i used document.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>(".mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected").style.backgroundColor = 'red'; and it gave me TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement>'.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>(".mat-step:nth-child(2) .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected").forEach(d => d.style.backgroundColor = red);